# Term for first person complement of the "Royal We"

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, pronouns, royal-we

The "*Royal We*" or [nosism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nosism) refers to the usage of "*we*" to mean "*I*", ("*We are not amused*", meaning "***I*** am not amused"), or "*you*", ("*We need to mop that floor*", which may mean "***you** must mop the floor*").

Is there some name or phrase for the usage of "*I*" to mean "*we*"?  For example, speaking of the [Keystone XL pipeline extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystone_Pipeline#Keystone_XL), Donald Trump said:

> I want it built, but I want a piece of the profits.

...which inspired a question on [SE Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/37207/did-trump-say-he-wanted-a-piece-of-the-keystone-xl-pipeline-profits?rq=1) about whether this was an expression of personal greed or [nationalist identification](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/10085/did-louis-xiv-actually-say-the-state-i-am-the-state-could-he-have-said-it); (answer: the latter).

Comment: It's a type of synecdoche (if actually true). ["l'état, c'est moi."](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/l'%C3%A9tat,%20c'est%20moi) See the [Hyperhistory article](http://www.hyperhistory.com/online_n2/people_n2/persons6_n2/louis.html).

Comment: Only slightly off the topic, Margaret Thatcher as Prime Minister, reacting to the complicated mess the early National Curriculum said:  “When I introduced the National Curriculum, WE never imagined that THEY would make it so complicated.  A revealing shift of pronoun!

Comment: “Answer: the latter” — doubtful. And not what the Skeptics question was about.

Comment: WRT the question title, what you meant to write was `complement`, not `compliment`. Regardless, `analogue`/`counterpart` is a better choice here.

Comment: @TusharRaj, Thanks, I hadn't known there were separate spellings.   *Complement* in the sense of "*To supply a lack; to supplement.*" seems preferable, as it better connotes the possibility there may be no such term.

Comment: On the contrary, complement of X (in one of its primary senses) suggests something that completes X, which might in turn suggest X was incomplete in the first place. But hey, it's your post. Go for it.

Comment: At the risk of flogging a deceased equine, “inverse”, “converse” and “contrapositive” are some other words that might fit in the question title.

Comment: No such thing could be, ever. The "Royal We" is a specific construct designed solely for if not quite God, at least God’s anointed. As such there could be no possibility of any comparison, anywhere. To my ear, even Edwin’s otherwise excellent "l'état, c'est moi." pales by comparison.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin, Please elaborate if any more substantive reasons exist for why such a term is impossible.  Edwin's comment seems redundant  to me -- it links to something initially noted in original post, (click on "*nationalist identification*" above).

Comment: agc please, which part of what I posted d'you not think axiomatic, please? Is God unique? Are God's anointed in a tiny minority, greatly fewer even than the number of countries? How could any other entity come close to their exalted position?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin, People use use air and water, it does not follow that air and water are necessarily  constructed or designed.  Similarly it is not axiomatic that any style or figure of speech favored by certain persons is a "*construct*" or is *designed* by or for those persons.

Comment: Thanks and please explain how the "Royal We" could ever be comparable to any "ordinary" part of speech?

If you see a similarity between "air and water" and "the Royal We" do, please, explain that.

What "style or figure of speech" are you talking about and how is that "favoured by certain persons", please?

To recap, "the Royal We" is utterly different from every other part of speech

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin,  No.  Re-explaining comments which do not seem especially obscure would not be profitable.

Comment: agc, would you mind sticking to the Question? It might matter why culture or heritage you grew up with or studied but either way, why is it difficult for you to accept that "Royal we" isn't even closely related to every-day, common-or-garden "we", please?

If it's me who's missing something here then please, anyone with English as a first language and raised in a monarchy show me where I went wrong…